# HttpClient error handling

Tags: java, android, recursion, exception-handling, error-handling

I would be happy to hear feedback on my implementation of HttpClient. I am not so strong with error handling so I want to improve. My thought process behind this was that [`IOException`s can be recoverable and should be tried again](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/exception-handling.html). Where as client exception isn't. Hope to hear your thoughts.

```
private HttpResponse execute(int httpVerb, boolean authHeader) throws NoInternetConnectionError, IOException, ClientProtocolException {

    try {
        Log.i(TAG, "setting header and executing");
        switch (httpVerb) {
        case HTTP_POST:
            if (authHeader){
                httpPost.addHeader(header); 
            }
            return httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        case HTTP_PUT:
            if (authHeader){
                httpPut.addHeader(header);
            }
            return httpClient.execute(httpPut);
        case HTTP_GET:
            if (authHeader){
                httpGet.addHeader(header);
            }
            return httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        default:
            return null;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        InternetChecker internetChecker = new InternetChecker(context);
        if (internetChecker.isInternetConnected() == false) {
            throw new NoInternetConnectionError("internet not connected");
        } else {
            numberOfTries ++;
            if (numberOfTries > 2) {
                throw new IOException(e.getMessage());
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "executing for the " + String.valueOf(numberOfTries) + " time");
                return execute(httpVerb, authHeader);   
            }
        }
    } finally {
        numberOfTries = 0;
        Log.i(TAG, "finally block run");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I would create a common `executeRequest` method:

   ```
   private HttpResponse executeRequest(final HttpUriRequest request, 
           final String authHeader, final boolean authHeader) {
       if (authHeader){
           request.addHeader(authHeader); 
       }
       return httpClient.execute(request);
   }
   ```

   then remove the code duplication from the `case` branches.

   ```
   switch (httpVerb) {
       case HTTP_POST:
           return executeRequest(httpPost, authHeader, header);
       case HTTP_PUT:
           return executeRequest(httpPut, authHeader, header);
       case HTTP_GET:
           return executeRequest(httpGet, authHeader, header);
       default:
           return null;
   }
   ```

   Anyway, it doesn't seem too good that you have `httpPost`, `httpGet` and `httpPut` at the same time.
2. Wouldn't it worth to check the result of `isInternetConnected()` at the beginning of the method? I'm not too familiar with Android development, maybe it's the best to put into the `catch` block. Anyway, if it is not a slow/costly service I would call at the beginning of the method too.
3. Calling `String.valueOf(numberOfTries)` seem unnecessary. I could be simply

   ```
   Log.i(TAG, "executing for the " + numberOfTries + " time");
   ```
4. I'd use a loop instead of recursion. Two links on the topic:

   - [Exceptions, and how best to retry when a connection is reset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198289/java-exceptions-and-how-best-to-retry-when-a-connection-is-reset)
   - [Retrying Operations in Java](http://fahdshariff.blogspot.com/2009/08/retrying-operations-in-java.html)

Comment: Thanks palacsint. Just a couple of questions if you don't mind. 

1. Why is it bad to have all 3 of them at the same time, after all I call the same method (execute) for each

2. The internet connection can be lost at anytime. It could be there at the start when I check then gone once I do the work

3. Didn't know I could put an in in there

Comment: I have modified my code and its fairly obvious why I shouldn't be using the case. Thanks a lot!

Comment: 1. Because two of the three always unnecessary. Post those parts (or the full code) as a new question and I'll check it. I think only one reference with `HttpUriRequest` type would be enough but it's hard to say more without the code.
2. Check the update please.

Answer (score 3):

In the end there was no need to retry manually httpclient has a retry handler.

```
    HttpRequestRetryHandler retryhandler = new DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler(6, true);

    httpClient.setHttpRequestRetryHandler(retryhandler);
```